# Android Button To Another Screen

Tags: android, button

i have a simple problem but it is giving me a big problem im sure it is something simple i am just missing.

I am trying to cerate a splash screen with a button that will go to the next screen at the moment the java code below creates a list of all the activitys in the manifest.

I am using the KanKan Wheel project BTW.

I want my java file to just have a simple button java command that links to one button on the xml file like so:

```
   Button bEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
    bEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("??????????????????"));


        }
    });
```

Usually where the "???" are you would just place the package name then .MATCHMANIFESTNAME but i cant seem to get this to work i think the java code below is adding something as it is making the links automatcilly.

At the moment the java file is:

```
public class WheelDemo extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String path = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.android.apis.Path");

    if (path == null) {
        path = "";
    }

    setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, getData(path),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "title" },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }));
}

protected List getData(String prefix) {
    List<Map> myData = new ArrayList<Map>();

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory("kankan.wheel.WHEEL_SAMPLE");

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

    if (null == list)
        return myData;

    String[] prefixPath;

    if (prefix.equals("")) {
        prefixPath = null;
    } else {
        prefixPath = prefix.split("/");
    }

    int len = list.size();

    Map<String, Boolean> entries = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ResolveInfo info = list.get(i);
        CharSequence labelSeq = info.loadLabel(pm);
        String label = labelSeq != null
                ? labelSeq.toString()
                : info.activityInfo.name;

        if (prefix.length() == 0 || label.startsWith(prefix)) {

            String[] labelPath = label.split("/");

            String nextLabel = prefixPath == null ? labelPath[0] : labelPath[prefixPath.length];

            if ((prefixPath != null ? prefixPath.length : 0) == labelPath.length - 1) {
                addItem(myData, nextLabel, activityIntent(
                        info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
                        info.activityInfo.name));
            } else {
                if (entries.get(nextLabel) == null) {
                    addItem(myData, nextLabel, browseIntent(prefix.equals("") ? nextLabel : prefix + "/" + nextLabel));
                    entries.put(nextLabel, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(myData, sDisplayNameComparator);

    return myData;
}

private final static Comparator<Map> sDisplayNameComparator = new Comparator<Map>() {
    private final Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();

    public int compare(Map map1, Map map2) {
        return collator.compare(map1.get("title"), map2.get("title"));
    }
};

protected Intent activityIntent(String pkg, String componentName) {
    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.setClassName(pkg, componentName);
    return result;
}

protected Intent browseIntent(String path) {
    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.setClass(this, WheelDemo.class);
    result.putExtra("com.example.android.apis.Path", path);
    return result;
}

protected void addItem(List<Map> data, String name, Intent intent) {
    Map<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    temp.put("title", name);
    temp.put("intent", intent);
    data.add(temp);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Map map = (Map) l.getItemAtPosition(position);

    Intent intent = (Intent) map.get("intent");
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

And the screen i want to link to in the manifest is defined as:

```
<activity android:name="kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity" android:label="Password" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="kankan.wheel.WHEEL_SAMPLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my experience, simply put:

```
Button bEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);     
bEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
public void onClick(View v) {             
// TODO Auto-generated method stub             

startActivity(new Intent("nameofthisclass.this, nameofotherclass.class"));           

}     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the intent, you need pass in which class is calling it and also what class you will be starting with that intent.. new Intent should be like this;

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, className.class);
```

this only works if you are in the activity, so that "this" is pointing to the active activity class.. And for the second variable you don't need package names.. Just use the className.class (and you will need to import the class into the activity obviously) and make sure that the className is an activity..

Also noe that className.class is NOT in quotes.

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is type:

```
Button bEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);     
bEnter.setOnClickListener(SetOnClickListener(this)           
public void onClick(View v) {             
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
  switch (v.getId()){     
    case R.id.Button Id:      
      startActivity(new Intent("package.PUT_WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_HERE"));           
  }     
}
```

Also, you have to go in the manifest and type this up:

```
<activity android:name="package.Java_Class_Name" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="package.PUT_WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_HERE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

remember that the PUT_WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_HERE thing has to be the same thing in the manifest and the java class.